# Most effecient way to calculate this in swift (simple math)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2

The question is related to calculating an increase in currency.

Loop over this n times, and let's say you start with $50k and your multiplier is 2. Something like b * 2 + a

This is the correct result:

```
$50,000.00
$100,000.00
$250,000.00
$600,000.00
$1,450,000.00
$3,500,000.00
$8,450,000.00
$20,400,000.00
$49,250,000.00
```

So just to be clear, the question is about efficiency in swift, not simply how to calculate this. Are there any handy data structures that would make this faster? Basically I was just looping through how many years (n) adding 2 (200%) and incrementing a couple temp variables to keep track of the current and previous values. It feels like there has got to be a much better way of handling this.

```
$50k base

$50k * 2 + 0 (previous value) = $100k
$100k * 2 + $50k = $250k
$250k * 2 + $100k = $600k
etc.
```

Code:

```
let baseAmount = 50000.0
let percentReturn = 200.0
let years = 10

// Calc decimal of percent.
var out: Double = 0.0
var previous: Double = 0.0
let returnPercent = percentReturn * 0.01

// Create tmp array to store values.
var tmpArray = [Double]()

// Loop through years.
for var index = 0; index < years; ++index
{
    if index == 0
    {
        out = baseAmount
        tmpArray.append(baseAmount)
    }
    else if index == 1
    {
        out = (out * returnPercent)
        tmpArray.append(out)
        previous = baseAmount
    }
    else
    {
        let tmp = (tmpArray.last! * returnPercent) + previous
        previous = tmpArray.last!
        tmpArray.append(tmp)
    }
}

println(tmpArray)
```

Comment: *"Or even just less code?"*: if you don't show your code in your question, we can't know *how much* code you have to begin with.

Comment: Ah right. Sorry about that. I guess I wanted to see how people would approach this without being tainted with an example. I'll edit my post.

Comment: It's all right. I'm just trying to contribute towards having better questions on SO. Also, without your code in it, you take the risk to have your question closed as "opinion based" or "unclear".

Comment: Ah ok, I'll add it when I get back at my desk.

Comment: There no computing problem in this question. All proper/obvious approaches have linear complexity, so you would have to do something very strange or very wrong to have performance issues here. Apparently you have different problem and you picking on wrong part t of code. This is bad SO question. You even didn't show code you have problem with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some ideas for improving efficiency:

- Initialize your array to the appropriate size (it isn't dynamic; it is always the number of years)
- Remove special cases (year 0 and 1 calculations) from the for-loop

Code:

```
func calculate(baseAmount: Double, percentReturn: Double, years: Int) -> [Double] {

    // I prefer to return an empty array instead of nil
    // so that you don't have to check for nil later
    if years < 1 {
        return [Double]()
    }

    let percentReturnAsDecimal = percentReturn * 0.01

    // You know the size of the array, no need to append
    var result = [Double](count: years, repeatedValue: 0.0)
    result[0] = baseAmount

    // No need to do this in the loop
    if years > 1 {
        result[1] = baseAmount * percentReturnAsDecimal
    }

    // Loop through years 2+
    for year in 2 ..< years {
        let lastYear = result[year - 1]
        let yearBeforeLast = result[year - 2]
        result[year] = (lastYear * percentReturnAsDecimal) + yearBeforeLast
    }

    return result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Efficiency in terms of speed I found this to be the fastest implementation of your algorithm:

```
let baseAmount = 50000.0
let returnPercent = 2.0
let years = 10

// you know the size of the array so you don't have to append to it and just use the subscript which is much faster
var array = [Double](count: years, repeatedValue: 0)
var previousValue = 0.0
var currentValue = baseAmount

for i in 0..<years {
    array[i] = currentValue
    let p2 = currentValue
    currentValue = currentValue * returnPercent + previousValue
    previousValue = p2
}

print(array)
```

Comment: Doesn't that answer your question?